# What is the right way to implement scheduled push notifications?

Tags: php, laravel-5, cron

I am doing project in laravel. I want to send push notifications to different users at different times. Like I can assign a follow up time to a user which can be different per user. I did search and got to know that we can use concept of cron jobs, but for that I need to run cron jobs at every minute, so that I can check whether it is time to send push notification or not. 
Is it ok to run cron job every minute? because I think, it will increase server load.

Can anyone give me advice for this, as I am new to this concept, I am really not getting what to do in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron job is a scheduled task that you can run on any time interval. It is OK to run it every 1 minute depending on your requirement.

You can increase the efficiency of your cron in this kind of a situation.

You run the file -> Check to see you have any notifications to send -> If you have continue your logic.

If you don't have anything you can just `exit;`

Meaning, it will give some load to the server only when you have some thing to do (which we should be doing). Running a cron every minute will not give you huge server load (again depends on how well you structure your code / db queries to optimize usage)

Hope this gives you a bit of head start!

Answer (score 0):

We can add cron in systems as per our convenience time. Use Following code to add code to send notificationto perticular user on perticular time.

```
$loc_cron_min   = 30;
$loc_cron_hour  = 12;
$loc_cron_date  = 20;
$loc_cron_month = 01;

exec('echo -e "`crontab -l`\n'.$loc_cron_min.' '.$loc_cron_hour.' '.$loc_cron_date.' '.$loc_cron_month.' * wget -qO /dev/null http://example.com/cron/sendsnotification.php?userid=1" | crontab -');
```

We can See all schedule cron using following line in php

```
$output = shell_exec('crontab -l');
    echo $output;
```

As per above code notification will be send on 20 Jan 2017 on 12:30. So you dont need to execute cron every minute. You can delete cron after excuting successfully.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I liked this concept to implement scheduled notification. I will try this and let you know if it works fine.

Comment: I have one doubt...To fetch records from database, I have to run cron for every minute, because their might be a case where follow up time of user would get changed. then it means at any case I have run it for every minute?

Comment: Yes. There is one alternative for this if follow up time get changed. Delete previous cron for that user and add new one. But it depends on your requirement.